# How could I have a form tag execute 2 actions?

Tags: html, post

I am trying to add a new functionality to a site and for this to work I need to use a form, the problem I am facing is that the location where I have to make this new functionality is already in a form and this form did not have an action but if I set the action to nothing it works too. My question is, How can I have the old form execute a new action and also still do the old action?

Here is my code if you want to see it:

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="/testement" action=""> <--- This is where I am trying to do the two actions
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      {{display_field(form.point_cle)}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label class="control-label" for="commentaire">Commentaire</label>
      <textarea name="the_comment" id="123soleil" class="form-control"></textarea>
      <input type="hidden" name="msr_id" value="{{msr.id}}">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="btn-{{pos.name}}" class="btn btn-{{pos.value.color}}" type="submit">{{pos.name}} - {{pos.value.action}}</button>
</form>
```

Comment: use javascript to perform both tasks

Comment: 2 actions in the same form wont post twice, you should us javascript to accomplish 2 separate form submits.

Comment: alright thank you for your feedback I will look into how this works and I will keep you posted.

Comment: @Tallboy are you suggesting that I should make a second form? Sorry I am quite new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few commentes said use JavaScript and they are correct - read about AJAX requests and then turn your submit- into a regular button.

In general - you **should not** do such a thing. The normal approach is for the */testement* page where you POST the form to perform the second action in addition to the first one. Why? The biggest problem is that if you start the two actions simultaneously then if the user refreshes the browser or is taken to a new page, the request for some of the two actions may be cancelled or may not even start (if the two operations are codependent).

The rule above applies to operations that meet the following criteria:

- mutate state
- need to complete together
- both are critical to the workflow

You can still query multiple pieces of data from the server as not reading part of the data (from one failed or cancelled call) is not a problem.

Comment: Alright thank you for your advice but If I were to make the /testement perform the second action, how should I do such a thing? Because my /testement is not realy a new page, it is just used to call a python function. Would this be the best way to handle this situation in your opinion?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, your python function runs on the backend on a always-on web server and can perform multiple operations (within reasonable time limits as you still want to take the user to another page). On the other part of your question - how this can be done in python, I assume it's a straightforward programming question - you merge the logic of the two functions you have and expose them as a single function behind /testement.

Comment: But the thing is that my form did not have an action at all at the beginning so I dont realy understand which function was getting executed, I'm trying to figure this out but I can't seem to understand it

Comment: Matt, the details are not clear enough to reconstruct how this project evolved and understand the problem. Can you share the code on github or similar?

Comment: Thank you for your advice and your help I managed to figure it out thanks to your help, it works perfecrly now I just had to find the right way to call my second function and I had to understand where it could be found but it's all good now! Thank you